# Find absolute path of the exe file using javascript

Tags: javascript

Can we get the absolute path of the specified `exe` file in `javascript`.

(i.e) If i give a file name like `quicme` and i want to get the path of the file name as

```
c://programfiles/quicme.exe
```

Comment: location.pathname gives you the absolute of the file

Comment: if it was possible, anybody would be able to scan your hard drive from a distant server, hopefully it's more likely impossible to do

Comment: I need an EXE files address.But it gives me the path of the file which i run.

Comment: Absolute path to file on server or on client? Not that either is possible directly, but there are solutions for specific problems such as reading the file.

Comment: file on client side only needed.In my pjct i need to run the EXE file from my application and take the values from that.Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript used in web pages, or JScript used in Windows Script Host?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. You'd need access to the `PATH` environment variable for that, and JavaScript in browsers does not have access to that.

In JScript on the Windows Script Host, you might be able to, though. (If that's the case, please add the appropriate tags to your question.)

Comment: OK thanks.So if i want to get the address of an exe file i need to use Jscript?

Comment: @Raja: JScript on Windows Script Host can do it. Unless you know you're using Windows Script Host, though, you probably aren't. Windows Script Host cannot be run inside of a web page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a wanted feature to be able to access the user environment variables within a client-side script, especially if it's from a distant server. There are serious security issues that could be exposed if it was allowed. Therefore, you cannot achieve that online with JavaScript.

However, if you want it offline, a solution might be to do it with WScript, which would lead you to something like that to read the PATH environment variable:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set colSystemEnvVars = objShell.Environment("System")
Set colUserEnvVars = objShell.Environment("User")
Wscript.Echo "Computer-specific PATH Environment Variable"
Wscript.Echo colSystemEnvVars("PATH")
Wscript.Echo "User-specific PATH Environment Variable"
Wscript.Echo colUserEnvVars("PATH")
```

For more information, take a look at this [reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee156595.aspx).